# calculating the scores using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on calculating the scores for air rifle paper target. I'm able to calculate the distance from center of the image to the center of the bullet hole in Pixels.

Here's my code:

```
I = imread('Sample.jpg');
RGB = imresize(I,0.9);
imshow(RGB);

bw = im2bw(RGB,graythresh(getimage));
figure, imshow(bw);

bw2 = imfill(bw,'holes');
s = regionprops(bw2,'centroid');
centroids = cat(1,s.Centroid);

dist_from_center = norm(size(bw(:,:,1))/2 - centroids,2);

hold(imgca,'on');
plot(imgca,centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2),'r*');
hold(imgca,'off');

numberOfPixels = numel(I);
Number_Of_Pixel = numel(RGB);
```

This is the raw image with one bullet hole.
[image]

This is the result I am having.

[image]

This is the paper target I'm using to get the score.

[image]

Can any one suggest me how to calculate the score using this.

Comment: If you have distance to the centre, that instantly gives you the score doesn't it? The score relates almost linear to the distance from the centre as far as I can see.

Comment: You just need to define the relation between distance and score. Use array with distances in one column, scores in the other, then use `find` with relation `<` to get corresponding distance.

Comment: @Stefan It's in pixels, so do I need to do some conversion or anything?

Comment: If you determine the distances to the borders between scores in pixels, then you need no conversion. Otherwise, if you have the distances in mm then you must calculate af conversion factor in pixels/mm.

Comment: @Stefan Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## See [my walk through your problem](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/OverkillGuy/8062b69d74edbb08e51d) in Python

It's a very fun problem you have.
I assumed you have already a way of getting the binary holes mask (since you gave us the image)

[image: Sample image]
*Some scores are wrong because of target centering issues in given image*

### Given hole-mask, find 2D shot center

I assume that the actual images would include several holes instead of one.

Shot locations extracted by computing the **local maxima of the distance transform of the binary hole image**. Since the distance transform gives as intensity output the distance from the examined point to a border, this allows us to compute the centermost pixels as local maximum.

Local maximum technique I used is computing a maximum filter of your image with a given size (10 for me) and find the pixels that have `filtered == original`.
You have to remove the 0-valued "maxima" but apart from that it's a nice trick to remember, since it works in N-dimension by using a N-dimensional maximum filter.

### Given a 2D position of shot center, compute the score

You need to transform your coordinate system from cartesian (X,Y) to polar (distance,angle).

Image from MathWorks to illustrate the math.

[image: Matlab image]

To use the center of image as reference point, offset each position by the image center vector.
Discarding the angle, your score is directly linked to the distance from center.

Your score is an integer that you need to compute based on distance :
As I understand you score 10 if you are at distance 0 and decrease till 0 points.

This means the scoring function is

```
border_space = 10 px # distance between each circle, up to you to find it :)
score = 10 - (distance / border_space) # integer division though
```

with the added constraint that score can not be negative :

```
score = max(10 - (distance / border_space),0)
```

**Really do look through my [ipython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/OverkillGuy/8062b69d74edbb08e51d), it's very visual**

**Edit**: Regarding the distance conversion.

Your target practice image is in pixels, but these pixel distances can be mapped to millimeters : You probably know what your target's size is in centimeters (it's regulation size, right ?), so you can set up a conversion rate:

```
target_size_mm = 1000 # 1 meter = 1000 millimeters
target_size_px = 600 # to be measured for each image

px_to_mm_ratio = target_size_mm / target_size_px

object_size_px = 102 # any value you want to measure really
object_size_mm = object_size_px * px_to_mm_ratio
```

Everytime you're thinking about a facet of your problem, think "Is what I'm looking at in pixels or in millimeters ?". Try to conceptually separate the code that uses pixels from the one in millimeters.

It is coding best practice to avoid these assumptions where you can, so that if you get a bunch of images from different cameras, with different properties, you can "convert" everything to a common format (millimeters) and have a uniform treatment of data afterwards